# Typescript: How to remove properties of object/mapped type by value

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

Is there a way to remove some props of an object via a mapped type based on their value? So similar to `Omit`, but discriminating by value, instead of key.

Given this example:

```
type Q = {a: number, b: never}
```

How could I remove b based because it is `never`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that you can construct a helper type in similar fashion to `Omit` like so:

```
type RemovePropsByValue<T, V> = {
  [K in keyof T as T[K] extends V ? never : K]: T[K];
};
```

Which can be used like so:

```
type Q = {a: number, b: never}
type FilteredQ = RemovePropsByValue<Q, never>; // typeof {a: number}
```

Comment: I had a hard time solving this, so I documented it here, in hopefully searchable terms. If you see some flaws or have a better solution, please let me know.